# How to write VBA code that looks to a cell for a column header in another sheet, then returns the corresponding column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

So I have a full spreadsheet of customers as columns and products as rows, the crossing cells indicating how many of each the customer has purchased.  In another sheet i want to be able to run a macro that will pull up all of the products and list the number purchased for just the one customer.

I have another macro that deletes the rows that are blank, leaving only the products that the customer has purchased.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: LOOKS LIKE A JOB FOR PIVOT TABLE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub prodList()
Dim cust As String, rLook As Range, msg As String
Dim ct As Variant, r As Range
cust = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Customer Name", Type:=2)
Set rLook = Range("1:1").Find(What:=cust, After:=Range("A1")).EntireColumn

msg = ""
For Each r In rLook.Cells
    pr = Cells(r.Row, 1).Value
    If pr = "" Then Exit For
    ct = CStr(r.Value)
    If ct <> "" Then
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & pr & vbTab & ct
    End If
Next r

MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Will display:[image]

***EDIT#1:***

To store the output on *Sheet2* use this macro:

```
Sub prodList2()
    Dim cust As String, rLook As Range, K As Long
    Dim ct As Variant, r As Range
    cust = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Customer Name", Type:=2)
    Set rLook = Range("1:1").Find(What:=cust, After:=Range("A1")).EntireColumn

    K = 1
    For Each r In rLook.Cells
        pr = Cells(r.Row, 1).Value
        If pr = "" Then Exit For
        ct = CStr(r.Value)
        If ct <> "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(K, 1) = pr
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(K, 2) = ct
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for, but is there a way to get that output in another sheet in excel?  This was just a dumbed down version of what I am actually looking to do with the data.  I plan on having information that is referencing the product and number and doing other calculations.

Comment: @Greg  See my **EDIT#1**